# What kind of serialized array is this?

Tags: php, arrays, database, wordpress, serialization

I'm trying to figure out what type of array is that:

I found it on a Wordpress database, how can I tranform into a json string?

```
a:6{i:0;s:3:\"948\";i:1;s:3:\"949\";i:2;s:3:\"951\";i:3;s:3:\"952\";i:4;s:3:\"953\";i:5;s:4:\"1742\";}
```

Comment: json_encode(unserialize($content));

Comment: It's a simple php serialized array? I'm using ruby.

Comment: Yes, it looks like standard PHP serialization.

Comment: Thank You, I'm thinking of use this lib https://github.com/jqr/php-serialize

Comment: Actually Wordpress is written in PHP, so it shouldn't surprise, that it uses PHP serialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the data is corrupted:

```
$content = 'a:6:{i:0;s:3:"948";i:1;s:3:"949";i:2;s:3:"951";i:3;s:3:"952";i:4;s:3:"953";i:5;s:4:"1742";}'
json_encode(unserialize($content));
```

Note the missing colon after "a:6"

Answer (score 0):

It seems like generated by serialize(), you can unserialize it by invoking the method unserialize()